# Python pickling from subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pickle

I am using python 3.7 (Ubuntu) and trying to pickle/unpickle objects through a subprocess but having an error:

```
encoding=encoding, errors=errors).load()
raise EOFError
```

basically in a subprocess doing something like `sys.stdout.write(pickle.dumps(return_obj))` then in the main process doing something like

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(...)
output, _ = proc.communicate()
return_obj = pickle.loads(output)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are otheruseful information.

Comment: you could create minimal working code which we could copy and run to test it.

Comment: Nvm, tried making a quick example and it works.  Turns out my issue was before it even writes to a pickle.  Sorry about that. Can close this one

Comment: you can write it as answer, mark your answer as accepted, and later upvote your answer.